# RxJS mix combineLatest and zip

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have two sources of streams that I want to listen to them. The requirements are:

1. If one emits give me also the last value from the second.
2. If two of them emits at the same time, don't call the subscribe two times.

The first case is combineLatest, but the second is zip. I need a way to mix combineLatest and zip into one operator.

```
const { Observable, BehaviorSubject} = Rx;

const movies = {
  ids: [],
  entities: {}
}

const actors = {
  ids: [],
  entities: {}
} 

const storeOne = new BehaviorSubject(movies);
const storeTwo = new BehaviorSubject(actors);

const movies$ = storeOne.map(state => state.entities).distinctUntilChanged();
const actors$ = storeTwo.map(state => state.entities).distinctUntilChanged();

const both$ = Observable.zip(
   movies$,
   actors$,
   (movies, actors) => {
     return {movies, actors};
   }
)

both$.subscribe(console.log);

storeOne.next({
  ...storeOne.getValue(),
  entities: {
    1: {id: 1}
  },
  ids: [1]
});

storeTwo.next({
  ...storeTwo.getValue(),
  entities: {
    1: {id: 1}
  },
  ids: [1]
});
```

The above code works fine when both emits one after the other, but I need to support also a case where one of them emits. (combineLatest)

How can I do that?

Comment: `Observable.combineLatest(movies$, actors$, (movies, actors) => ({ movies, actors })).auditTime(0)`

Comment: Can you explain, please?

Comment: Don't really have the time to write a decent answer at the moment. If no one else does, I might do so later. Or you could check out the [docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-auditTime).

Comment: I like your answers, you are very helpful, I will wait, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as advised by [@cartant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6680611/cartant) you can use `Observable.combineLatest(movies$, actors$, (movies, actors) => ({ movies, actors })).auditTime(0)`

To elaborate the above,

1. `auditTime(n)` will wait for `n` milliseconds and emit the latest value.
2. `auditTime(0)` is similar to `setTimeout(0)`, it actually waits for nothing *(executes immediately)*, but waits for the current event/execution loop to complete.

[image: Example]

Here values `B` & `2` are emitted together, so when you use combineLatest you would get either `B1`,`B2` or `A2, B2` (which is based on the internal clock). Regardless `B2` is the latest value in that execution loop. Since we are waiting for `0 milliseconds` i.e. for the current execution loop to get the latest value via `auditTime(0)`, the observable would emit only `B2`.